# SQL Join three tables one vs. others two

Tags: join, subquery, sql-server-2014-express

I did the example code below as an example of what Im facing.

Lets say a Have this tables:
**STOCK** : where I have my current stock picture day by day.
**ProductType** : Where I have the information if an product in my stock is an fruit.
**FruitePrices** : Where I have an historical price for each Fruits prices.
**OthersPrices** : Where I have an historical prices for other kind of products.

I need for a giving stock date load all the historical prices whether it is a fruit or other.

So first I need to do a **Join** between **STOCK** and **ProductType** to return the column **IsFruit** (bit column) from the **ProductType**. And I just know do do this join for a giving stock day.

Then I need to build an historical price tables for this Products that My above join return. **If IsFruit = 1** get the price from **FruitePrice** tablem, **if = 0** get from **OthersPrice** table.

The problem Im facing is that Lets say I'm looking for my products on Stock for **10Apr15** and doing my fist **join** between **STOCK** and **ProductType** I return:

```
StockDate   Product IsFrute
10Apr15     Banana   1
10Apr15     Milk     0
```

Then I do the second Join to return Banana and Milk Prices from eachs respective tables since 10Jan15 till 10Apr15.

**I wish to see the historical price of Banana and Milk this way:**

```
StockDate PriceDate Product Price
10Apr15   10Jan15 Banana     NULL
10Apr15   10Jan15 Milk       4
10Apr15   11Jan15 Banana     7
10Apr15   11Jan15 Milk       11
10Apr15   ...     Banana     8
10Apr15   ...     Milk       3
10Apr15   10Apr15 Banana     5
10Apr15   10Apr15 Milk       2
```

I may not have missing dates on historical prices for a product, this case should return **NULL**. Above example Banana just start to have price since 11Jan15 then should returned NULL for 10Jan15

Finally, the problem Im having is that I'm having in above table one row for each combination on dates its like n x n x n.

**Example what I was doing:**

```
Select GP.PriceDate, GP.ProdName, case(GP.IsFrute = 1, FP.Price, else OP.Price)
(
    Select STK.PriceDate, STK.ProdName, PT.IsFrute
    from Stock as STK
    Join ProductType as PT on PT.ProdName = STK.ProdName
) as GP
join FruitPrice as FP on FP.Name = GP.ProdName
join OthersPrice as OT on OP.Name = GP.Name
Where GP.PriceDate = '10Apr15'
and FP.Date >= '10Jan15' and FP.Date <= '10Apr15'
and OT.Date >= '10Jan15' and OT.Date <= '10Apr15'
```

My Real data, breaking down dates for each table to be visible what is happening:

```
Refdate     Date        Date    Price
2015-05-13  2015-05-04  NULL    2650.000000000000
2015-05-13  2015-05-05  NULL    2650.000000000000
2015-05-13  2015-05-06  NULL    2650.000000000000
2015-05-13  2015-05-07  NULL    2460.000000000000
2015-05-13  2015-05-08  NULL    2490.000000000000
2015-05-13  2015-05-11  NULL    2660.000000000000
2015-05-13  2015-05-12  NULL    2660.000000000000
2015-05-13  2015-05-13  NULL    2770.000000000000
2015-05-13  2015-05-14  NULL    2610.000000000000
2015-05-13  2014-12-31  2015-05-06  1490.000000000000
2015-05-13  2014-12-31  2015-05-07  1490.000000000000
2015-05-13  2014-12-31  2015-05-08  1490.000000000000
2015-05-13  2014-12-31  2015-05-11  1490.000000000000
2015-05-13  2014-12-31  2015-05-12  1490.000000000000
2015-05-13  2014-12-31  2015-05-13  1490.000000000000
2015-05-13  2014-12-31  2015-05-14  1490.000000000000
2015-05-13  2014-12-31  2015-05-05  1490.000000000000
2015-05-13  2015-01-02  2015-05-06  1490.000000000000
2015-05-13  2015-01-02  2015-05-07  1490.000000000000
2015-05-13  2015-01-02  2015-05-08  1490.000000000000
2015-05-13  2015-01-02  2015-05-11  1490.000000000000
2015-05-13  2015-01-02  2015-05-12  1490.000000000000
```

**UPDATE 2:**
**Real query**

```
With cte_RiskFactors(RiskFactor)
AS
(Select RiskFactor, ProdId, from Exposure where Refdate = '20150513')
Select Expo.refdate, expo.riskfactor, expo.ProdId, px.price
from cte_RiskFactors as cte
join Exposure as expo on cte.RiskFactor = expo.RiskFactor
join Prices as px on px.Id_Product = cte.ProdId
where px.[Date] >= '20150501' and px.[Date] <= '20150513'
UNION
Select Expo.refdate, expo.riskfactor, iv.Value
from cte_RiskFactors as cte
join Exposure as expo on cte.RiskFactor = expo.RiskFactor
join IndexesValue as iv on iv.Id_RiskFactor = cte.IdRF
where iv.[Date] >= '20150501' and iv.[Date] <= '20150513'
```

Error:

```
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 62
Invalid column name 'IdRF'.
Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 59
Invalid column name 'price'.
```

Comment: Can you be specific about your problem? What are the expected results and what are the actual result? Can you show them in a table? IMO a good question would include something specific like "This price should not be null, it should be X because of reason Y". Also consider adding an example on www.sqlfiddle.com

Comment: Im receiving an row for each combination of stockdate, fruitdate and othersdate .

Comment: now its included in the end.

Answer (score 0):

Would this work (using a CTE to get products as of 10Apr15)  The CTE creates a smaller subset of products to join your table on. Since you have a table of FruitPrices and a Table of OtherPrices do you need the flag isfruit? Here is the TSQL code:

```
WITH cte_products( ProdName)
AS
(SELECT Prodname FROM Stock WHERE PriceDate = '10Apr15')
SELECT STK.PriceDate, STK.ProdName, Coalesce(FP.Price,OP.Price)
FROM cte_products cte   
JOIN Stock STK ON cte.Prodname = STK.Prodname
LEFT OUTER JOIN FruitPrice FP ON cte.Prodname = FP.Name
LEFT OUTER JOIN Othersprice OP ON cte.Prodname = OP.Name
WHERE STK.PriceDate >= '10Jan15' and STK.PriceDate <= '10Apr15'
```

Comment: where are you checking if IsFruit = 1 from ProcutType table?

Comment: I am assuming that the table FruitPrice contains only prodnames and prices of fruits only and the table Otherprice contains only prodnames and prices of other products not fruits.  Is that a correct assumption?

Comment: if that is the case then there is no need for the isfruit flag...since you already have all the information you need in those 2 tables.

Comment: My bad, lets say in real wen Its Fruit I do my join using Prodname and when its Others I'll use other column from STOCK lets say Prodname2. thats why I need to first join with table ProductType to check if its a Fruit or Others. Im including an update2 with my real query

Comment: note that my need to verify if its Fruit is a Product can have a Prodname that match with FruitsPrice tabel and also have a Productname2 that match with a OthersPrice table and I dont want to return it two time the Criteria to know what shoul be used is the IsFruit = 1 I go to Prodname and join with FruitPrice and if IsFruit = 0 I use Prodname2 to join with OthersPrice

Comment: I changed the query based on your criteria.  The first with the Union statement should still work since it only selects distinct rows.  The edited query seems better. change the joins to outer joins and use the function coalesce ( you could also use isnull) which will pick up the first non null value it finds.